# Can we apply a permutation test to compare two percentage distributions?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, python, permutation-test, frequency

Any help here will be greatly appreciated!

Suppose we have two groups, one composed of ET's from Mars and another from ET's from Jupiter (assuming there are ETs there).

Then, these groups of ETs meet in a friendly space tournament to run over a circular circuit. They just need to appoint and run and, if they like it, they can do it again and again.

Now, suppose that, for this tournament, we gathered the following data and we want to test whether the difference in the willingness to run circuits was statistically different depending on the ET planet.

```
index,planet,circuit_runs,number_of_appointments,gave_up,percentage_gave_up
0,Jupiter,0,343,145,0.42
1,Mars,0,325,119,0.37
2,Jupiter,1,98,48,0.49
3,Mars,1,99,37,0.37
4,Jupiter,2,49,31,0.63
5,Mars,2,42,15,0.36
6,Jupiter,3,24,19,0.79
7,Mars,3,17,9,0.53
```

This gives us the following distributions:

[image]

What is the correct test to check whether the distribution of the percentages are statistically different in this case? Is it possible with a permutation test using the percentage gave up column?

Comment: There isn't a single correct test, but rather a number of possible tests, though there may be some typical ones. Are you assuming that the proportions vary within planet, across individuals?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, first of all thank you for reading this and commenting out. You are right about some typical events, so let's say that the correct test here is the the best procedure using the optimal statistic for the problem :) 

Let's say that the proportions can vary across individuals too, but the planet they come from might influence as well (this is exactly what we would like to test here, this dfference). So, given the distribution of proportions:

H0: mean_mars = mean_jupiter
H1: mean_mars != mean_jupiter

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question about variation in proportion "within planet" (your response addresses *between* planet variation not "between individuals within planet" - not every athlete is equally fit/motivated and so may have a mix of  underlying 'willingness'). When you say  'best' and 'optimal' answers will depend on what you want to optimize/be best at; if you choose power, then depending on the specific model used there may well be no uniformly most powerful test (in which case it will depend on the alternatives you want to optimize power against)

Comment: hey, @Glen_b thanks again. Ok, so let's assume that the proportions do not vary across individuals within a planet.